# Return value where no result in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

This is probably javascript 101 but I would appreciate the help. I want to return a different value in this Meteor helper when there is a null return. Any ideas?

```
Template.singleComment.helpers({
momentTime: function () {
    return moment(this.createdAt).fromNow();
},
byWho: function(){
    if(Meteor.users.findOne({_id: user}).username){
        return this.username;
    } else {
        return "none"
    }
}
```

})

Comment: Change the `return "none"` to what you want?

Comment: you can return null;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it had something to do with handing errors with findOne where there is no callback. This works.

```
Template.singleComment.helpers({
momentTime: function () {
    return moment(this.createdAt).fromNow();
},
byWho: function(){
    user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.createdBy})
    if(user){
        return user.username;
    } else {
        return this.createdBy;
    }
}
})
```